# HID vs USBXpress timing on SiLabs C8051F320

Tags: hid

I have a 2-byte SPI transaction in HID and USBXpress firmware on the C8051F320. The SPI routines are the same in both firmwares.

Running two back-to-back transactions, there is a 1ms delay between transactions in USBXpress and a 2ms delay using HID. The delays are consistent. Why is the HID slower and how can I make it 1ms? bInterval in HID is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Going a bit on a lark here (no experience with USBXpress, and merely some experience with Microchip's USB stacks):

HID stack would use two USB frames to do a back-to-back transaction - if I recall it correctly, there could never be two HID transactions outstanding (i.e. one report request followed by one report response). The first one is in the first USB frame, the first response is in the second USB frame, and the second request can only happen in the third USB frame.

With USBXpress, one can relax that condition and make the next request before waiting for the completion of the previous one.

Can it be made into 1ms? I'd suggest reading HID specification to find out if it's legal.. and if so, how can host be forced to handle two outstanding HID transactions.

Comment: Hi, I put a USB analyzer on it. On USBXpress I see one SOF (that takes 3us) every 1ms, but on the HID there are are 2 SOFs that take 1ms total, so the OUT transaction doesn't start until that 1ms passes, and the next SOFs come 2ms later. Why is this?